# Restore old terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have modified my terminal via `wget -O https://teejeetech.com/scripts/jammy/install_nala | bash`. Now, I want to restore my terminal. Can you help me change it?

Answer (score 5):

You installed the package `nala`.

You can uninstall the package with:

```
sudo apt remove nala
```

*Note: if you want to remove the program and it's config files, do: `sudo apt remove --purge nala`*

Then remove the installed repository and key files with:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/volian-archive-scar-unstable.list
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/nala-volian-scar-keyring.gpg
```

Please note that installing this package has not done anything to your terminal.

It adds the command `nala`, but as long as you don't run that command, nothing is different.